# using onresume to redirect activity after pressing back

Tags: android

I have an activity that I use when my android app is opening to validate information about the user logging in.  There is not a `GUI` for this `Activity` and it's intended to redirect to other Activities based on validation information.  Somehow my app will go back to this screen and just be stuck on an empty Activity.

I have not coded an `onResume`.

Would I use `onResume()` as well as removing it from the back stack to prevent this?

Thank you!

Comment: why do you neeed to write another activity just for validating??, something wrong in your implementation

Comment: You better don't use an activity just for validation.

Answer (score 0):

when you successfully Validate user information in first "Activity" before going to 2nd activity ,call

```
finish(); //this will remove previous Activity from the stack
```

hope this will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely not a good idea to define an activity for validating things.Just to answer your question no its not necessary to code onResume().onResume() is just a method which is called after onCreate() in an activity life cycle.
You can finish() the activity right in your onCreate() to prevent it from loading on press of back button.